# Computing orthogonal projection onto range space of a given matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

I have matrix $A =\begin{bmatrix}
  2 & -2 & 0 & 0  & 0  & 0 \\
  -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 2 & -2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -2 & 2 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -3 & 2 & 5 & -4 \\
0 & 0 & 2 & -3 & -4 & 5 \\
\end{bmatrix}$

I have to caclulate $P_{R(A)}$, where $P_{R(A)}$ denote the orthogonal projection on the range space $R(A)$. Could anybody help me how to calculate $P_{R(A)}$ ?

Thank you very much for your kind help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: The orthogonal projection matrix is given by $P=A(A^T A)^{-1}A^T$.

If $A$ is singular with SVD $A = USV^T$ where $U = [U_r ; U_{n-r}]$ where $A$ has rank $r$ the orthogonal projection onto the range of $A$ is given by $U_r U_r^T$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. $(A^tA)$ may not be non singular?